# Miktex 2.9 pgfplots, circuitikz library collision problem

Tags: pgfplots, circuitikz

In my book, I use both libraries. After Miktex **update** yesterday evening (circuitikz ver 0.3 pgfplots 1.11), I have problem with compiling following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}     % TikZ and PGF picture 
  \usepackage{circuitikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw  (0,0) to [short, *-] (6,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

```
*Command line listing*:
  Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable
tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset<compact=1.11> into 
your preamble.

!Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@multiply@thousand

1.20 (0,0) to [short, *-] (6,0)
```

I haven't idea where is mistake. When I delete pgfplots package from testin code, it 
works fine, but in my book I need both packages. Circuitikz code was used from `http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/induction-machine/`so I see no reason why it should not work.

Comment: Not really related to the problem, but it seems to me that the correct option is `compat`, not `compact`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: OK pgfplotsset is removed

Comment: Can you load pgfplots after circuitikz? I think one of them

Comment: @percusse I tried it, but no effect. The program was working before I made MiKTeX upgrade.

Comment: I have the last upgrade of  MikTeX, and your MWE work just fine.

Comment: @jafan Rather than removing `\pgfplotsset`, try adding the suggested line with `compat` rather than `compact`. That said, the code compiles fine as is here (but I'm not using MiKTeX).

Comment: This question turns out to be a true duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219217/undefined-control-sequence-pgfmathmultiplythousand/219473#219473 . I have just posted an answer there and a list of possible work-arounds in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217933/problem-using-atan-in-pgfplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution but my words on this.

I also use MiKTeX 2.9 on my windows machine and updated MiKTeX 2 days ago via the MiKTeX update manager.

Your MWE compiles fine for me.

I added a `\listfiles` in the preamble of your MWE and show you the output in the log file:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
circuitikz.sty    2012/12/29 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0.3
.0
pgfplots.sty    2014/08/04 v1.11 Data Visualization (1.11-3-g4c99d7a)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: I see that my tikz.sty and pgf.sty are both in the version 2010/01/15 v2.10, but I am sure that I did update all Miktex packages. I dont understand this.