# Problem using atan in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot something using atan in pgfplots, but it always results in hundreds of errors.

I'm using an example I found here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     width=160pt,compat=1.5.1,grid style={ultra thin},every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
     x tick label style={font=\tiny},y tick label style={font=\tiny},
     scale only axis,grid=major,axis lines=middle,
     xlabel={$x$},
     ylabel={$y$},
     xmin=-200,
     xmax=200,
     domain=-200:210,
     ymin=-5.5,
     ymax=5.5,
     xtick={-150,-100,...,150},
     ytick={-5, -4,...,5},
     restrict y to domain=-20:20,
     legend style={at={(0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north,nodes={right}},
 ]
 \addplot[mark=none,color=blue, samples=500]{rad(atan(x))};
 \addlegendentry{$y = \tan^{-1}x $};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The errors are:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pgfmath@multiply@thousand 

l.23 ...ne,color=blue, samples=500]{rad(atan(x))};

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@basic@atan@ ... pt \pgfmath@table@lookup 
                                                  {\pgfmath@x }{pgfmath@atan...
l.23 ...ne,color=blue, samples=500]{rad(atan(x))};

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.23 ...ne,color=blue, samples=500]{rad(atan(x))};
```

And it goes on and on. Over hundred errors and then it stops compiling with no result at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It runs fine with pgfplots 1.8 -- Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)

Comment: I don't have any problem either. You have conflicting compat keys and it should be outside the axis environment. I think you have an outdated version. Put `\pgfplotsversion` somewhere after the `\begin{document}` to see what it is. Latest version is 1.11

Comment: Hm, i also have version 1.11 installed. I put the full log here: http://pastebin.com/UirsSrwm

Maybe someone can find the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your log file, you have `pgfplots` 1.11 and `pgf` 2.10 . I can reproduce the problem in this combination.

It works with both packages up to date (i.e. `pgfplots` 1.11 and `pgf` 3.00).

It works with `pgfplots` 1.10 and `pgf` 2.10.

Solutions alternatives for you are:

1. upgrade PGF to 3.00 or
2. downgrade pgfplots to 1.10 or
3. use `\addplot ... gnuplot {atan(x)};` for the time being.

**EDIT** It turns out that this problem is actually worse than anticipated: the reports in [Undefined control sequence: \pgfmath@multiply@thousand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219217/undefined-control-sequence-pgfmathmultiplythousand/219473#219473) and [Miktex 2.9 pgfplots, circuitikz library collision problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200799/miktex-2-9-pgfplots-circuitikz-library-collision-problem?rq=1) appear to have the same root cause.

The root cause is that `pgfplots` attempts to patch the old PGF version; but that patch fails to apply (i.e. it is a bug in `pgfplots`).

To workaround it, you can proceed according to option (1) or (2). Or you can add the lines

```
% HACK: deactivate feature 'trig format' but restore compatibility
% between pgfplots 1.11 and tikz 2.10:
\csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{pgfmathiftrigonometricusesdeg}{%
    \def\pgfmathiftrigonometricusesdeg#1#2{#1}%
}{}%
```

*before* loading `pgfplots`. In this case, it will assume that everything is up-to-date and will not attempt to apply the broken patch. Risk of applying this patch: the feature `trig format plots` introduced in `pgfplots` 1.11 will not work. But it will eventually (probably with the version which will come after PGF 3.0.0).

Comment: Thank you very much. I never would have guessed that. Now it work perfectly!