# Undefined control sequence: \pgfmath@multiply@thousand

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, miktex, shapes

After updating my MiKTeX distribution, I suddenly got a compile error with a .tex file that compiled perfectly fine before. After removing everything that did not contribute to the error, I ended up with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=rounded rectangle, draw=black] {bla};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I use `rectangle` instead of `rounded rectangle` or if I remove the pgfplots package, everything works well.

As a workaround, I'm using `rectangle` with the `rounded corners` attribute for now, but I would like to know whether there is also a possibility to use `rounded rectangle` together with pgfplots (and if so, how).

My pgfplots package has version 1.11. When inspecting the version of my pgf package with the MiKTeX Package Manager, it shows version 3.0.0. However, when inspecting the logfile, it shows that version 2.10 is used.

For the sake of completeness: Moreover I'm using MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14) (MiKTeX 2.9) on a Windows 7 Professional (Service Pack 1) OS.

The error message I get with the example above is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pgfmath@multiply@thousand

l.12 ...hape=rounded rectangle, draw=black] {bla};
```

While searching for related questions, I found these other questions here:

[Miktex 2.9 pgfplots, circuitikz library collision problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200799/miktex-2-9-pgfplots-circuitikz-library-collision-problem?rq=1)

[Problem using atan in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217933/problem-using-atan-in-pgfplots)

It seems this is a case of different symptoms for the same disease (as discussed in the meta: [Same disease, different symptoms](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/same-disease-different-symptoms)). At least the error message is the same and the situation (problem occurred after update) is similar.

I first thought the solutions there would not apply to my problem as I have both pgfplots in version 1.11 and pgf in version 3.0.0 (which should work according to the accepted answer of the latter question). However, by checking the logfile it turns out that version 2.10 of pgf is actually used. So the underlying problem seems to be identical with the former of the two related questions. How is this difference between the Package Manager and the logfile possible and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does Cygwin have to do with MiKTeX?

Comment: The current version of MiKTeX is: `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.7.29)`.  What do you with Cygwin? Running some bash programms for MiKTeX?  I guess you installed MiKTeX and later Cygwin, because MiKTeX does not run under Cygwin as far as I know.  Please add more information to your question, for example the steps you compile (were do we find Cygwin tere?) ...

Comment: I'm using MikTeX (without Cygwin!) pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) under Win7, and I have no problem compiling your example. Why you need Cygwin here ? Are you using Linux version of MikTeX under Cygwin ?

Comment: I just run pdflatex from a Cygwin bash (and have reconfigured Cygwin to use MiKTeX instead of TeX Live). But I have the same problem when compiling this example with the TeXworks program (Version 0.4.5) shipped with MiKTeX. The same holds if I run pdflatex from the Windows command line. So the Cygwin part is probably irrelevant.

Comment: It would be better to load `shapes.misc` if you are using version 3 but it shouldn't break anything to use `shapes`.

Comment: I also tried that, but it does not change anything.

Comment: This sounds like some strange bug or incomplete update.  Could you inspect the log file to see which version of pgf is active? Since this might easily become lengthy and the issue might be localized, I suggest that you send your log files to me. As package author of `pgfplots`, I have an interest to repair such problems with high priority. You can find my address in the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger You've got email. By inspecting the logfile I saw that the pgf package is used in version 2.10. But if I inspect this package using the MiKTeX Package Manager, it shows version 3.0.0. How is this possible and how can I enforce the use of version 3.0.0 for the pgf package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information that MikTeX actually failed to update PGF to 3.0.0, I am able to confirm that this is a duplicate of [Problem using atan in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217933/problem-using-atan-in-pgfplots) and [Miktex 2.9 pgfplots, circuitikz library collision problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200799/miktex-2-9-pgfplots-circuitikz-library-collision-problem?rq=1) .

I will update [Problem using atan in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217933/problem-using-atan-in-pgfplots) to provide workarounds.

There are actually two distinct problems:

1. I introduced an incompatibility between `pgfplots` 1.11 and PGF 2.10 . I am sorry for it; the next release of pgfplots will come with a solution (planned for beginning 2015).
2. According to the reports, MikTeX claims that it updates to PGF 3.0.0, but it does not. If both packages were at their current stable releases, everything would be fine. I do not know details about this update problem.

Please see [Problem using atan in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217933/problem-using-atan-in-pgfplots) for possible workarounds.