# Circuitikz problem getting inductor

Tags: circuitikz

I have troubles obtaining the right shape of an inductor using `circuitikz`. I am getting a black filled rectangle instead :

[image: circuitikz bug ?]

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to[european inductor](2,0);
\draw(0,0)to(0,-.25)to[ground](0,-.5);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

I am using Windows 7 and MiKTeX 2.9, which I just updated. 
Thank you.

I missed the fact that the `european inductor` is indeed correct. It seems like the true issue is with `cute inductor`, or simply `L` : I get the following error message :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@sh@bg@cuteinductorshape ...mationadjustments
\par \pgfmathsetlength {\p...
l.8 \draw (0,0) to [L] (2,0)
;
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I suspect there is a connection with this question : [Miktex 2.9 pgfplots, circuitikz...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200799/miktex-2-9-pgfplots-circuitikz-library-collision-problem)

Comment: In fact the inductor is just an example, because the ground doesn't work either...

Comment: On my TeXLive distribution your code does only compile if I remove the babel package.

Comment: @marmot Mine too. You can add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to make it work.

Comment: @Montes Looking at the documentation of `circuitikz`, the `european inductor` [looks correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dI7x.png).

Comment: The filled rectangle is the European style (which you've selected with `european inductor`). You can try `cute inductor` or `american inductor` to see the other styles. Also check out the options listed in the manual to set the styles globally so you don't need to type out the style for each and every inductor in your diagrams.

Comment: I have edited my question considering your answers.

Answer (score 3):

- you should add `tikz` library `babel` (it remove changes introduced by french babel in `tikz` code)
- `ground` is node

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) to [european inductor] (2,0)
        (0,0) -- (0,-0.25) node [ground] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

edit: with use `L` for inductor:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) to [L] (2,0)
        (0,0) -- (0,-0.25) node [ground] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) I can't make `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` work : I get `! I can't find file `tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex'.`

Comment: 2) Which may me more serious, when I delete this line, I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@sh@bg@cuteinductorshape` etc.  which means `L` doesn't work...

Comment: @Montes, it seems that you have outdated `tikz` and `circuitikz` packages. probably the best way is to first remove both packages from `latex` installation and then reinstalled and after then check if exist updates for your latex installation. you can also try just last of mentioned step. i use `tikz 3.0.1a` and `circitikz 0.8.3 (2017/05/28)`.

Comment: I've just reinstalled the whole latex distribution and I still get `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/handle active characters
in code' and I am going to ignore it.` + `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@sh@bg@cuteinductorshape ...mationadjustments
\par \pgfmathsetlength {\p...
l.10 \draw (0,0) to [L] (2,0)
;`...

Comment: is this the only installation of `latex` on your computer? which version of the package `circuitikz` you have now?

Comment: also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/tikz-declare-function-and-babel-french-option

Comment: I had indeed other LaTeX installations on my computer... The latest version of `circuitikz` is now properly used, and everything's perfect. Thanks !

Comment: @Montes, i'm glad that you succeed to fix your `latex` installation. happy tex-ing!